# I have .DCU but not .PAS

Tags: delphi, compiler-errors, dcu

I am migrating some software from Delphi 6 to RAD 10.3. I have a line of code that I am receiving an error on and am not really sure how to resolve it. The line is:

```delphi
uses LMDSpeedButton, ExtCtrls, StdCtrls, LMDEdit,ovcsf, Forms, ovcmeter,SDL_replis
```

The error I am seeing is:

> [dcc32 Fatal Error] ScreenResolution.pas(25): F2613 Unit 'SDL_replis' not found.

I searched for `SDL_replis` and found the `SDL_replis.dcu` but not .PAS. It is my understanding that when using "uses" I need to have the .PAS. Is that correct and how do I get past this?

Answer (score 3):

> It is my understanding that when using "uses" I need to have the .PAS. Is that correct

No. The compiler will use a `.dcu` file if found, and then fall back to a `.pas` file if needed.

However, `.dcu` files are version-specific. So, you can't use a D6 `.dcu` file in RS10.3. If you don't have the original `.pas` file to recompile the `.dcu` in RS10.3, and can't otherwise install an updated version of SDL into RS10.3, then you are likely out of luck.  Your only option would be to write a `.dll` in D6 that wraps the desired logic from the `.dcu`, and then use that `.dll` in RS10.3.